# Object not orienting correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a small script that causes an object to bounce back and forth. It is a bird for an upwards scrolling endless runner. So it represents its flight path. This script moves it from one end to the other and when it reaches the end it flips the 2D sprite and travels in the opposite direction. It works most of the time. But the problem is that sometimes the image flips twice so now it looks like its flying backwards until it does it again. Each time it does it it appears to be random.

```
public class Fly : MonoBehaviour  {

private bool dirRight = false;
public float speed;
public bool facingRight = false;

void Start (){
    speed = Random.Range (15.0f, 22.0f);
}

void Update () {

    if(transform.position.x >= 25.0f) {
        dirRight = false;
        Flip();
    }

    if(transform.position.x <= -25.0f) {
        dirRight = true;
        Flip();
    }

    if (dirRight)
        transform.Translate (Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    else
        transform.Translate (-Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
}

void Flip()
{
    // Switch the way the player is labelled as facing
    facingRight = !facingRight;

    // Multiply the player's x local scale by -1
    Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
    theScale.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = theScale;
}
```

I modified the if statements and use my bools as well as the position as such:

```
if(transform.position.x >= 25.0f && dirRight == true) {
        dirRight = false;
        Flip();
    }

    if(transform.position.x <= -25.0f && dirRight == false) {
        dirRight = true;
        Flip();
    }
```

I am running it now and waiting to see if it works.

Comment: Have you tried to log `transform.position` whenever `Flip` calls ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are calling `Flip()` method based on position. and position is updated per frame. So it takes time to Lerp from `>=25` to `<25` so in every frame when position is `>= 25` or `<= -25` it calls to `Flip()`. So you need to add another check for calling `Flip()`. May be `facingright == true` will work.

Comment: I added my change above based on your answer. I am just running it now to make sure it works. It looks like it is so far but I want to let it run about another 20 minutes before I say gtg.

Comment: Honestly I was thinking about doing it like this at work earlier but I wasn't exactly sure if it would work and if it would why it would work. Thank you for the explanation =)